Changing values in an Array
My problem is basically as follows:

That is, I want to change some values in an array according to a list of "transactions".
In the picture, you can see only 2 transactions but there can be many more.
I have achieved a solution for half of my array:

But I cannot get to the desired final array, after all the transactions have been processed. I am a bit lost.
Any hints are highly appreciated

MAKEARRAY() with FILTER() may help.

This is quite possible without using any LAMBDA() helper function, here is one alternative:


• Method One: Formula used in cell C14
=LET(
     a, C5:F8,
     b, TOCOL(a),
     c, ROWS(b),
     d, COLUMNS(a),
     e, MOD((SEQUENCE(c)-1),d)+1,
     f, INT((SEQUENCE(c)-1)/d)+1,
     g, MMULT((f=TOROW(H11:H12))*(e=TOROW(I11:I12))*TOROW(J11:J12),{1;1}),
     h, WRAPROWS(IF(g=0,b,g),d),
     h)


For the above method if for any instance there is a 0 as new value, then it will return false positives, as already mentioned by rotabor Sir, therefore can use the amended version as well.
=LET(
     a, C5:F8,
     b, TOCOL(a),
     c, ROWS(b),
     d, COLUMNS(a),
     e, MOD((SEQUENCE(c)-1),d)+1,
     f, INT((SEQUENCE(c)-1)/d)+1,
     WRAPROWS(IFNA(XLOOKUP(f&"|"&e,
                           H11:H12&"|"&I11:I12,
                           J11:J12),b),d))


Toggle around the variables to find what each of those returns.
Change this {1;1} to, if its multiple, with some other alternatives -->
SEQUENCE(ROWS(J11:J12))^0


Or,
SEQUENCE(ROWS(J11:J12),,1,0)


• Method Two: Another crude way i believe is using XLOOKUP() and IFNA()

=IFNA(XLOOKUP(B5:B8&"|"&C4:F4,H11:H12&"|"&I11:I12,J11:J12),C5:F8)


To use with LET() for the above:
=LET(
     α, C5:F8,
     δ, SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),
     ε, SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(α)),
     IFNA(XLOOKUP(δ&"|"&ε, 
                  H11:H12&"|"&I11:I12, 
                  J11:J12), α))


• Method Three : Using REDUCE()
=REDUCE(C5:F8,J11:J12,LAMBDA(a,v,
 MAKEARRAY(B8,B8,LAMBDA(r,c,
 LET(L,TAKE(+H12:v,1),IF((r=@L)*(c=(@DROP(L,,1))),v,
 INDEX(a,r,c)))))))


• Method Four: Using MAP()
=LET(
     a, IF(SEQUENCE(,4),B5:B8),
     b, IF(SEQUENCE(4), C4:F4),
     IFNA(MAP(a,b,LAMBDA(x,y,
     XLOOKUP(1,(H11:H12=x)*(I11:I12=y),J11:J12))),C5:F8))



Method One doesn't work if a new value is 0.

@rotabor if a which means it may or may not be. What are the chances of having a new value as 0 can you predict or say? Well it can be modified. Also, I have posted one other method.

I see the numbers as values and don't see any restriction for a value to be 0. Thus, we should not exclude 0.

I attentively analyze and collect the best techniques provided such experienced users as you, but some tricks look excessive. SEQUENCE(ROWS(J11:J12))^0 is one of those. It can be replaced by the clear expression SEQUENCE(ROWS(J11:J12),,1,0) or MAKEARRAY(ROWS(J11:J12),,LAMBDA(I,j,1)).

You may try MAKEARRAY() with FILTER() function.
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(C5:F8),COLUMNS(C5:F8),LAMBDA(r,c,FILTER(J11:J12,(H11:H12=r)*(I11:I12=c),INDEX(C5:F8,r,c))))



=IFNA(XLOOKUP(ROW(B5:E8)-4&-COLUMN(B5:E8)+1,H11:H12&-I11:I12,J11:J12),B5:E8)
Where ROW(B5:E8)-4 is the row # of the input range minus correction (4 in this case) to start at 1.
For the column # the same logic applies, but because I added a minus sign in front (to act as delimiter), we need to add the correction (+ instead of -):  -COLUMN(B5:E8)+1

It's a smart trick to join search criteria over a delimiter.

In this case the minus is the delimiter

@Rotabor I see @MakukhBhattachayra his logic of method two is almost the same (or mine the same as his, since he posted prior to mine). He made use of the helper cells, which, combined with mine, would make it: =IFNA(XLOOKUP(A5:A8&-B4:E4,H11:H12&-I11:I12,J11:J12),B5:E8)

ROW() and COLUMN() don't work in an array, am I wrong?

@JvdV https://i.sstatic.net/W1XyBYwX.jpg

That's not an array though, just cell references. Have a try with an actual array, I don't believe it's possible since your dealing with elements instead of cells in that case.

Maybe I'm just lost in terms of terminology but OP mentioned an array but has shown a range. The two are not the same.

This answer is similar logic to mine. Only tweaking few things to make it look different.

@MayukhBhattacharya true, the minus is a shortcut. Jvdv gotcha, no, ROW and COLUMN require a range indeed. In that case we needs SEQUENCE(ROWS()) and SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS()). But his own formula logic shows he's using a range.

For older versions of Excel:
=IFERROR(
INDEX($A$1:$E$4, ROW(E4)-ROW($A$1)+1, COLUMN(E4)-COLUMN($A$1)+1) +
SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$3=(ROW(E4)-ROW($A$1)+1)) * ($H$2:$H$3=(COLUMN(E4)-COLUMN($A$1)+1)) * ($I$2:$I$3 -
INDEX($A$1:$E$4, ROW(E4)-ROW($A$1)+1, COLUMN(E4)-COLUMN($A$1)+1))),
INDEX($A$1:$E$4, ROW(E4)-ROW($A$1)+1, COLUMN(E4)-COLUMN($A$1)+1))



Another way,

process source row by row REDUCE("Mapped", r_indices
map the row if there's mapping
IF(IFNA(XMATCH(r, in_row), FALSE), map_row(r), CHOOSEROWS(src, r)

=LET(src, C5:F8, mapping, I6:K7, in_row, INDEX(mapping, , 1),
  r_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(src)), c_indices, SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(src)),
  map_row, LAMBDA(r, MAP(c_indices,
    LAMBDA(c, LET(
      in_rows, FILTER(mapping, in_row = r),
      XLOOKUP(c, INDEX(in_rows, , 2), INDEX(in_rows, , 3), INDEX(src, r, c)))))),
  DROP(REDUCE("Mapped", r_indices, LAMBDA(acc,r,
    VSTACK(acc, IF(
          IFNA(XMATCH(r, in_row), FALSE),
          map_row(r),
          CHOOSEROWS(src, r)
        )))),1))




Formula in C14:
=LET(i,C5:F8,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(i),COLUMNS(i),LAMBDA(r,c,XLOOKUP(TRUE,BYROW(H11:I12=HSTACK(r,c),AND),J11:J12,INDEX(i,r,c)))))

